# In docusign can i request status for a list of envelope ID

Tags: docusignapi

I am exploring docusign API. 
I am trying to understand if the following is possible with status API

Is it possible to request the status for a set of Envelope Ids. I have seen the documentation for requesting status for ONE envelope id.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can easily request statuses for a set of envelopes through the DocuSign API.  I recommend going through the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) which introduces tools such as the API Explorer and the API Walkthroughs in the Getting Started section.

Take a look at the 5th (middle) walkthrough here, titled *Get Status of Envelopes* -
http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs

The walkthrough shows you the api call in 6 languages (PHP, Java, Javascript, C#, Python, Objective-C) for getting status of a set of envelopes.  Using URL params you can filter by status and date.

The API call you need to make is:

**Method**

```
GET
```

**URI**

```
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes
```

**Optional URL params**

1. from_date (url encoded)
2. status (filter by real-time envelope status)

As mentioned the from_date needs to be URL encoded.  For instance, to filter all envelopes that are sent, delivered, or completed since March 1, 2014, you would append the following to the URL:

```
/envelopes?from_date=3%2F1%2F2014&status=sent,delivered,completed
```

Comment: Great. the information is really helpful. I felt many REST features which are not completely documented. THanks for you guys being there!!!!. For example this once worked for my purpose exactly. <host>accounts/:accountId/envelopes?status=delivered,signed,completed,declined,processing&envelope_ids=request_body. The body had the JSON of envelope IDs worked exactly i wanted.

Comment: I would like to see an example of statuses where only the envelope Ids that I specify are included. It seems like the list of envelope ids I specify is ignored and response includes all envelopes with specified status.       e.g. /restapi/v2/accounts/123456/envelopes?envelope_ids%5B%5D=20555244-43bc-47c2-b5bf-a72c4bc8a0b0&envelope_ids%5B%5D=7dc889cd-eba8-40de-91f5-f2b9404cf965&envelope_ids%5B%5D=2113a451-e4b3-4f32-974a-0104b9df2dd1&from_date=2015-01-21&status=completed does not work!

Answer (score 2):

Yes DocuSign allows [retrieving statuses for multiple envelopes](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Status%20for%20more%20than%20one%20envelope.htm).

However, I actually found the above documentation to be inaccurate and missing some info.  The HTTP method should be `GET` and the parameter should be named `envelope_ids`.

So that would give you an example query of:

```
GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/status?envelope_ids=abc,def
```

The response contains the standard DocuSign pagination fields, but they don't seem to be processed if included in the request.  There is no mention in the docs as the maximum number of envelopes that can be retrieved at a time.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer!

Comment: This can also work as a PUT request. Use the URL: /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/status?envelope_ids=request_body. In the body of the request, use a JSON array of envelope ids (as shown in the "Example Request Body" section of the docs Will Norris linked to above). Note that the array of envelope IDs must be the value of an "envelopeIds" key. It's terribly inconsistent key names (underscores in URL vs camel case in the request body).